# Optimum tournament fixture organization

Tags: convex-optimization

The argentine FA Major league tournament is made up of 26 teams which play in a league system facing each other only once, whether home or away, making up a 25-week-long league. Every team plays either 12 games played away and 13 home or vice-versa (decided on a draw).
After this, the fixture should be organized in such a way that the travelling hours difference between teams remains as small as possible. The teams are spread around the country following way:
11 teams belong to the GBA, the urban area made up by the Buenos Aires autonomous city and its surroundings; The cities of La Plata, Santa Fe, Rosario, Córdoba, and San Miguel de Tucumán host two teams each; also one team belongs to San Juan city, one to Mendoza city, one to Mar del Plata, one to Bahía Blanca and one to Paraná.
A) How can this be organized in an optimum way?
B) Is it possible to build up a way to organize this systematically privileging one or many teams over the rest?

Comment: If anyone needs it I can upload a link with the distances noted but it's really information you can easily Google.

Comment: In part, this may depend on how you how you measure equity.  Do you want to minimize the difference between the distance traveled by the team which travels most and the distance traveled by the team that travels least, or have you some other measure in mind.  Also, you should upload the link with the distances, rather than making people Google them.  BWT did you mean to say "organize this systematically WITHOUT privileging ..."

Comment: I gotta do the whole document. Since you ask for it I guess I will. And no, I did mean organizing to privilege some team because IRL there is some suspicion about the whole thing.

Comment: Don't do it for me.  I don't know that I'll work on this.  I thought you had it already.  However, if someone does this for you, I think you should gather the data, rather than expecting him to do it.